# Throws Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes') in the first render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, react-router-dom

I want to map through an array that is inside an object and see if the array contains the `teacherId` and store it in a state, then map it so the `<Section />` component can render it.

```js
const teacherId = details.id;

const [availableSection, setAvailableSection] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
  const availSection = sections.map((section) => (
    section.teachers.includes(teacherId) ? section : null
  ))
        
  setAvailableSection(availSection);

}, [sections])
```

In the first transition to the `"/dashboard"` page it returns an error, `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')` but if I refresh the page again it will render just fine. How can I fix this problem?

After going to the `"/dashboard"` page, I want to instantly show the `<Section />` component.

here's my code:

parent:

```
function Dashboard() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch(getSections())

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getSections());
  }, [dispatch])

  const location = useLocation()

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Hello {location.state.teachersDetail.userName}</h1>
      <h1>This is where the chart and cards are located</h1>
      <Sections details={location.state.teachersDetail} />
    </>
  )
}

export default Dashboard;
```

Sections component:

```
function Sections({ details }) {
  const sections = useSelector((state) => state.sections)

  console.log(sections);

  const teacherId = details.id;

  const [availableSection, setAvailableSection] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const availSection = sections.map((section) => (
      section.teachers.includes(teacherId) ? section : null
    ))
        
    setAvailableSection(availSection);
  }, [sections])

  return (
    !sections.length
      ? <CircularProgress />
      : (
        <Grid
          container
          direction="column"
          justifyContent="flex-start"
          alignItems="stretch"
          style={{margin:'0 auto'}}
        >
          {availableSection.map((section) => (
            section !== null
              ? (
                <Grid key={section._id} item xs={12} sm={6}>
                  <Section section={section}/>
                </Grid>
              )
              : null
          ))}
        </Grid>
      ) 
  )
}

export default Sections
```

here's the section object:

sectionName: "ICT-5B",
teachers: (3) ['1', '2', '3'],
_id: "63f493ed77a87fdd1723d553"

Comment: `section.teachers` is undefined. Can you [edit] to share what the selected `section` state value looks like? Are you really just wanting to filter the `sections` array if there is a `teachers` array that includes `teacherId`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`section.teachers` is undefined. If you are really just wanting to filter the `sections` array if there is a `teachers` array that includes `teacherId` then I suggest the following that uses a null-check on the *potentially undefined* `section.teachers` property.

```js
const sections = useSelector((state) => state.sections);

const teacherId = details.id;

const [availableSection, setAvailableSection] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  const availSection = sections.filter(
    (section) => section.teachers?.includes(teacherId)
  );
    
  setAvailableSection(availSection);
}, [sections, teacherId]);

...
```

Also note that `availableSection` is what we consider to be derived state and it's a general React anti-pattern to store derived state in local React state. Just about any time you have a `useState/useEffect` pair what you really want to use is the `useMemo` hook.

Example:

```js
const sections = useSelector((state) => state.sections);

const teacherId = details.id;

const availableSection = useMemo(() => {
  return sections.filter(
    (section) => section.teachers?.includes(teacherId)
  );
}, [sections, teacherId]);

...
```

If you don't need the selected `sections` state *other than* to compute the `availableSection` value then you can move the logic into the `useSelector` hook.

Example:

```js
const teacherId = details.id;

const availableSection = useSelector((state) => state.sections.filter(
  (section) => section.teachers?.includes(teacherId)
));

...
```

Comment: it still gives me the same error in the first render, though if i refresh the page it will render the <Sections /> just fine and the error is gone.

Comment: @CharlzIvanJohnBabida Oops, I placed the null-check on the wrong property. I'll update. Sorry, I guess that's what happens when the coffee hasn't kicked in just yet.